# Property 'logItem' does not exist on type 'AppComponent' when using ternary operator

Tags: angular

ngStyle calls getColor() in component.html:

```
<div 
  *ngFor="let logItem of log" 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(logItem)}" 
  [ngClass]="{'white-text': logItem >= 5}">{{ logItem }}
</div>
```

In component.ts my method works as long as I use `if/else` like so:

```
getColor(logItem){
  if (logItem >= 5) {
    return 'blue';
  } else {
      return 'green';
    } 

    //return this.logItem >= 5 ? 'blue' : 'white';
  }
}
```

But I get an error when I try to use ternary op.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first look, you should juse use **`logItem`**  instead of **`this.logItem`**

```
return logItem >= 5 ? 'blue' : 'white';
```